# how to index polygon data in Lucene

Tags: java, solr, lucene

How can I add polygon data to Lucene index. Below is the code snippet which I use

```
 private SpatialContext ctx;
ctx.readShapeFromWkt("POLYGON((-10 30,-40 40,-10 -20,40 20,0 0,-10 30))")
```

But it give the exception with message 
**Unknown Shape definition [POLYGON((-10 30,-40 40,-10 -20,40 20,0 0,-10 30))]**

While same format works fine in solr. What should I use instead of this format or way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SpatialContext` does not support "POLYGON" (see [WktShapeParser](https://spatial4j.github.io/spatial4j/apidocs/com/spatial4j/core/io/WktShapeParser.html)).

[`JtsSpatialContext`](https://spatial4j.github.io/spatial4j/apidocs/com/spatial4j/core/context/jts/JtsSpatialContextFactory.html) adds support for polygons.

You may need to get the [JTS topology suite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jts-topo-suite/) added to your classpath first.  Then set your `spatialContextFactory` to `com.spatial4j.core.context.jts.JtsSpatialContextFactory`.